# An idiom or an expression to describe a worthwhile investment

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idioms, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Let's say we have a single mom with three kids (aged 6 to 8), who all want bikes. Our mom loves her kids, but she also has to be frugal.

She doesn't think it's smart to get them brand-new bikes as the kids will outgrow them in a year or so. Plus, they might not like riding at all when they try it.

So she might go for basic used bikes at first. When her oldest is a teen, he'll get a brand-spanking bike with all the bells and whistles. It'll hopefully last him for years.

**What would be an idiomatic way to describe the mom's reasoning?** (The shorter, the better.)

As in, "I'm not getting all of them new bikes, it's not a worthwhile investment". Or: "Now that Mark is 13, he can get a fancy new bike. It's a worthwhile investment now".

(Example sentences are just guidelines, totally malleable.)

Edit #1: A single word would work too.

Edit #2: I'm trying to specifically emphasize two aspects here: (A) **the timely/untimely nature** of the possible investment and (B) **the cost-to-benefit ratio** associated with it.

Edit #3: I'm looking for a common idiom, something the mom would use in everyday speech.

Comment: What's wrong with "worthwhile investment"?  Of course, one can use "wise investment", "smart investment", etc, but they're all about equivalent.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, just need a more colorful and idiomatic way.

Comment: A prudent expenditure.

Comment: Perhaps "spend money at worthy ends", but not colorful enough to be happy with it :(

Comment: @Cerberus i like *prudent*. Perhaps there's an idiom leveraging that.

Comment: "opportune expense" ? (*still not an  idiom*). Another possibility would be the dutch proverb saying "set your expense according to your trade".

Comment: She needs to [*cut her coat according to her cloth*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/you-should-cut-your-coat-according-to-your-cloth).

Comment: @Graffito: Or, slightly different meaning, this one near my house: https://c1.staticflickr.com/7/6220/6209688421_4bc4550bbc.jpg

Comment: @Cerberus: May you translate ?

Comment: @Graffito: Ah, I thought you read Dutch. *De kost gaat voor de baat uit* "cost goes before revenue". It means something like that you must invest before you can make a profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can come up with is that she got **more bang for her buck**. She got more value with the bike which can be passed down to the younger children.

> value for the money spent; excitement for the money spent; a favorable cost-to-benefit ratio

[http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bang+for+the+buck)

Comment: Thank you. I think It sounds a bit too pragmatic and calculating in the given context, but I'll upvote it.

Comment: Thanks, this comes closest compared to other suggestions.